# Change text and get text in text-area at specific line/column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the exact line/column the user typed a character at in a text-area (such as 2,60 - being line 2, column 60) and change the character in a text-area at a specific line?

Comment: Change the same character that was just written? Also, what have you tried? This is not a code writing service. This is a show-us-your-code-and-we'll-help service.

Comment: I literally have no clue where to start, I looked around and couldn't find anything. So I'm asking if anyone knows a function for doing such. And no, I'm just asking if there's a function for getting the line/column in a text-area the user typed a character at (which updates every character type of course). And then a function for changing text at certain lines/columns. And if so, where documentation is for such. Because I cannot find it anywhere

Comment: Okay, so. After an hour of searching, I have come to the conclusion that there is no definitive way of finding the number of lines in a textarea. So either I'm quite unlucky (or unskilled) at googling things, or then this is a very tough thing to do. The problem is the automatic line wrapping that cannot be counted as `\n`, so we can only approximate the number of lines with the help of pixel heights. And even after that we would still somehow have to find the number of characters in the last line. Which again is hard since we don't have monospace fonts all the time.

Comment: Wow! You really spent some time on this. Thank you (: I decided I'm going to just code my own 'text-area' type of thing in Jquery. That should do the trick